# how to return processed result from forkJoin

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have an array of userIds. For example: `['jd', 'abc']`. And I'm looping through the userIds to fetch for full names through api. In the end, I want to turn above array into `[ {userId: 'jd', name: 'John Doe"}， {userId: 'abc', name: 'full name'}]`.

code below: I tried returning `arrEnriched` inside subscribe and also tried returning outside the forkjoinm. Both didn't work as expected.

```
getUserObj(arr){
   const arrEnriched = [];
   forkJoin(arr.map((item)=> { 
      return this.userService.getUserName(item).pipe(pluck('name'));
   })).subscribe( (arrayOfHits)=>{
      const names = arrayOfHits.map(...);   // transform data
      arrEnriched = names.map(...);   // map from full name to object
      console.log(arrEnriched);  // as expected here 
      //return arrEnriched;

   });
   // return arrEnriched;
}
```

And then I'm trying to use this function in my `ngOnInit()`

```
ngOnInit(){
     this.childOneComponent.users = this.getUserObj(this.arrUsers);
     this.childTwoComponent.users = this.getUserObj(this.anotherArrUsers);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `getUserObj()` is asynchronous. You cannot return data from it synchronously. You could instead return the observable and subscribe to it where the data is required. Try the following

```js
getUserObj(arr): Observable<any> {
  return forkJoin(arr.map((item) => {
    return this.userService.getUserName(item).pipe(pluck('name'));
  })).pipe(
    map(arrayOfHits => {
      const names = arrayOfHits.map(...);   // transform data
      return names.map(...);                // map from full name to object
    })
  );
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getUserObj(this.arrUsers).subscribe((arrEnriched) => {
    this.childOneComponent.users = arrEnriched;
  });

  this.getUserObj(this.anotherArrUsers).subscribe((arrEnriched) => {
    this.childTwoComponent.users = arrEnriched;
  });
}
```

You could find more information about how to access async data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/6513921).